# Why does Gai look like Rock Lee?

Tags: naruto

Why does Gai-sensei and Rock Lee look almost exactly the same? Are they from the same clan or are they blood-related? Hinata and Neiji look the same and they're cousins, same with Sasori and Gaara, Sasuke and Itachi, so they're probably blood-related, or they're not? Are there any explanation regarding this?

Comment: As far as I can recall Sasori and Gaara are not related

Comment: Chiyo was Sasori's grandmother. Chiyo felt guilty for having sealed Shukaku in Gaara, but there was no blood relationship between the two.

Comment: Well they are not related. I actually think Lee could look a lot different if he had less bushier eye brows. He had a different look before he joined Guy's squad. But he tries to copy him so much now that they look very much identical.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, they are not blood-related. When Lee wasn't in Guy-sensei's team yet, he was often mocked and bullied because of his inability to use any techniques other than Taijutsu. Guy-sensei was the first one to really believe in Lee's abilities, and thus he became Lee's idol. From the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Lee):

> When first joining Team Guy Lee's appearance changed drastically. He had shorter hair than before that curved upwards in the back. He still maintained the Chinese appearance, since he wore a robe and a martial arts belt around his waist. After joining Might Guy's team, his appearance changed considerably to emulate his idol and sensei.

Here's an image of how Lee used to look:

[image]

So, as you can see, he just changed his appearance to look more like Guy whom he idolizes.

Comment: His eyebrows didn't change :D

Comment: @MrPineapple, well they seem to become thicker :P